# Cannot Keep Scroll Bar at Bottom

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code:

```
<div id="conversationDiv" style="overflow:auto">

    <label>What is your name?</label><input type="text" id="name" />
    <button id="sendName" onclick="sendName();updateScroll();">Send</button>
    <p id="response"></p>

</div>
```

And I have this javascript function which I run after I click on 'Send' button and it keeps running after 1 second interval.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function updateScroll() {
        setInterval(function(){ var element = document.getElementById("conversationDiv");
        element.scrollTop = element.scrollHeight; }, 1000);
    }
</script>
```

This is my sendName() function if anyone wants to see:

```
function sendName() {
        var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
        stompClient.send("/app/hello", {}, JSON.stringify({ 'name': name }));
    }
```

But the problem is, my scroll bar is never at the bottom.

I am running a Websocket connection and the information keeps coming and coming and when information is enough for scroll bar to appear, I don't want it to go up. I would like it to stay at bottom unless a user scrolls back up him/herself. I don't know why my code is not working. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I hope you are having `ajax` inside `sendName()`. If so, why don't you call `updateScroll();` after `success` of `ajax` and appending the `data`?

Comment: Does your `stompClient` have any `success` callback? i.e. any callback function that can be executed after successful response from server?

Comment: seems to work for me https://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/863vpwbe/2/

Comment: You got me wrong.. Once you receive success from server, is there any option to execute some other lines of code? like callback function. For ex. `ajax` has `success` option to handle requests which are successful..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting a timer using `setInterval()`. Either change your code to:

```
function updateScroll() {
  var element = document.getElementById("conversationDiv");
  element.scrollTop = element.scrollHeight;
}
```

Or just add one simple code in `document`'s `ready` event:

```
setInterval(function() {
  var element = document.getElementById("conversationDiv");
  element.scrollTop = element.scrollHeight;
}, 1000);
```

*Unless I myself scroll up...*

Okay, here's the tricky bit. You might consider adding a `flag` to the timer, so that when the scroll is made on the top direction, you can clear the timer.

**The full code...**

```js
$(function () {
  var count = 1;
  setInterval(function () {
    $("#conversationDiv").append('<p>Message #' + count++ + ': Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Praesentium repudiandae doloribus unde, repellat maiores minus fuga earum esse, ab, aperiam voluptatibus est dolorem placeat perferendis omnis libero dolore alias quasi!</p>');
  }, 1000);
  setInterval(function() {
    var element = document.getElementById("conversationDiv");
    element.scrollTop = element.scrollHeight;
  }, 500);
});
```

```css
* {font-family: 'Segoe UI'; margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none;}

#conversationDiv {height: 350px; overflow: auto; border: 1px solid #ccc;}
#conversationDiv p {margin: 5px 5px 10px; padding: 5px; border: 1px solid #ccc; background-color: #f5f5f5;}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script><div id="conversationDiv">
  
</div>
```

Comment: @FarazDurrani Explaining you with a snippet.

Comment: @FarazDurrani The way you have added `functions`, and `setInterval` is the difference. Have a look now.

Comment: @FarazDurrani ha ha... Sorry... Just look at the last `setInterval` code. Others are just for generating the messages.

Comment: Can I ask you a question on this very topic?

Comment: @FarazDurrani Yeah, sure go ahead.

Comment: if you run your own answer by clicking "Run code snippet", you will see that when a new content comes, it scrolls down to the bottom. Which is all well and good. But, if I scroll up, it doesn't stay there. As soon as new data comes, it scrolls back down. Is it possible that when I load a web page, and if I don't touch the scroll then let the scroll stay at the bottom like currently it is. But if I touch the scroll, then it should be there where I take it.

Comment: @FarazDurrani True, you need to set a flag, when user changes the scroll top.

Comment: @FarazDurrani While I work on your solution, would you mind asking another new question, related to this, so that I can answer it.