# Keep the scroll at the bottom unless user changes the position of the scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css

A few days ago I [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37300618/4828463) how can I keep my scroll bar at the bottom when new data comes in. I got [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37300840/4828463) which worked perfectly fine for me. But now I have a new requirement. I want the scroll bar to stay where I take it. For example, when the page loads and if I don't touch the scroll bar, then the scroll bar should remain at the bottom. But if I touch it and take it up, then it should stay there and not come down automatically.

This is the code I have:

```
<style>
#conversationDiv {
height: 900px;
overflow: auto;     
} 
</style>

<script>
$(function () {
  setInterval(function() {
    var element = document.getElementById("conversationDiv");
    element.scrollTop = element.scrollHeight;
  }, 0);
});
</script>


<div id="conversationDiv">
```

EDIT: I am posting the full code below which shows where the messages are coming from and where they are getting appended to what div.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Hello WebSocket</title>
<script
src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sockjs-client/1.1.0/sockjs.js">   </script>
<script
src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/stomp.js/2.3.3/stomp.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<style>
#conversationDiv {
height: 900px;
}
</style>
<script>
 $(function () {     
  setInterval(function() {       
   var element = document.getElementById("conversationDiv");
    element.scrollTop = element.scrollHeight;
   }, 0);
});  
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var stompClient = null;
    function setConnected(connected) {
        document.getElementById('connect').disabled = connected;
        document.getElementById('disconnect').disabled = !connected;
        document.getElementById('conversationDiv').style.visibility = connected ? 'visible' : 'hidden';
        document.getElementById('response').innerHTML = '';
    }

    function connect() {
        var socket = new SockJS("http://twitchbot-farazdurrani.rhcloud.com:8000/hello/");
        stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
        stompClient.connect({}, function(frame) {
            setConnected(true);
            console.log('Connected: ' + frame);
            stompClient.subscribe("/topic/greetings", function(greeting){
                showGreeting(greeting.body);
            });
        });
    }

    function disconnect() {
        if (stompClient != null) {
            stompClient.disconnect();
        }
        setConnected(false);
        console.log("Disconnected");
    }

    function sendName() { //I am not sending anything so remove this..
        var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
        stompClient.send("/app/hello", {}, JSON.stringify({ 'name': name     }));
    } 

    function showGreeting(message) {
        var response = document.getElementById('response');
        var p = document.createElement('p');
        p.style.wordWrap = 'break-word';
        p.appendChild(document.createTextNode(message));
        response.appendChild(p);
    }        
</script>
</head>
<body onload="connect()">
<div>
    <div>
        <button id="connect" onclick="connect();">Connect</button>
        <button id="disconnect" disabled="disabled" onclick="disconnect();">Disconnect</button>
    </div>
    <div id="conversationDiv" style="overflow:auto">            
        <p id="response"></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

A little info on what's going on: It is a **one way** chat system (Using WebSockets) where **only one side send messages**. That is server side. All the magic is happening in **function showGreeting(message) {..}** where it is creating elements and appending child, etc. I hope this could be of little help. 
Thanks

Comment: Yea... Working on it.

Comment: Can't you take the initial scrollHeight and compare it to the current one to determine if you should scrollTop or not ?

Comment: @Alexandre That's what I did. But for some reason it isn't working. Can you debug my code?

Answer (score 1):

For this you might need a flag. So what I am doing is:

1. When the scroll event is fired (gets fired even when appending), we need to check if the scrolled part is at the end.
2. If it is not end, we need to clear the interval.
3. If it is the end, reinitialise the interval.

Not sure why it isn't work. I have got the script I was working here.

```js
$(function () {
  var count = 1;
  setInterval(function () {
    $("#conversationDiv").append('<p>Message #' + count++ + ': Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Praesentium repudiandae doloribus unde, repellat maiores minus fuga earum esse, ab, aperiam voluptatibus est dolorem placeat perferendis omnis libero dolore alias quasi!</p>');
  }, 1000);
  var scr = setInterval(function() {
    var element = document.getElementById("conversationDiv");
    element.scrollTop = element.scrollHeight;
  }, 500);
  $("#conversationDiv").scroll(function () {
    var element = document.getElementById("conversationDiv");
    if ((Number(element.scrollTop) + Number($(element).height())) != (Number(element.scrollHeight)))
      clearInterval(scr);
    else
      if (element.scrollTop < element.scrollHeight)
      scr = setInterval(function() {
        var element = document.getElementById("conversationDiv");
        element.scrollTop = element.scrollHeight;
      }, 500);
  });
});
```

```css
* {font-family: 'Segoe UI'; margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none;}

#conversationDiv {height: 350px; overflow: auto; border: 1px solid #ccc;}
#conversationDiv p {margin: 5px 5px 10px; padding: 5px; border: 1px solid #ccc; background-color: #f5f5f5;}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<div id="conversationDiv">
  
</div>
```

Looks like something is missing. I am almost near it. Should something be there in the area of `Number(element.scrollTop)`, `Number($(element).height())`, `Number(element.scrollHeight)`.

Comment: can you take a look at this http://jsfiddle.net/dotnetCarpenter/KpM5j/ it works in that jsfiddle but not for me

Comment: @FarazDurrani Man! Great. Lemme fix it now. We need to do it in the interval itself. LoL.

Comment: if that is giving you problem then look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18614545/4828463

Comment: @FarazDurrani Man... See this: http://jsbin.com/jonoxafuva/edit?js,output

Comment: @FarazDurrani That doesn't work, because every time you insert a new message, it fires a `scroll` event.

Comment: @FarazDurrani I got the answer. Wait.

Comment: @FarazDurrani See if this works? http://jsbin.com/jonoxafuva/edit?js,output

Comment: yes it is working xD let me try that on my actual code

Comment: it is not working on my actual code. If you want you can look at it here http://twitchbot-farazdurrani.rhcloud.com/ and look at the source. it is not working

Comment: @FarazDurrani Trying.

Comment: I am editing my question. I mean I am posting the full code which shows where the messages are coming from and where they are getting appended to what div. That might make it easy for you

Answer (score 1):

You can figure out if you are scrolled to the bottom like this

```
var isScrolled = (element.scrollHeight - element.scrollTop === element.clientHeight);
```

then:

```
if (isScrolled) { 
   //code here to move scrollbar down
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollHeight

Comment: Wooh. Thanks. Lemme check.

Comment: I have tried both `isScrolled` and `!isScrolled` to suit my answer, but didn't help!

Comment: open fireBug or other debugger in your browser, and console.log element.scrollHeight - element.scrollTop === element.clientHeight it should be returning true or false