# Append <li> to the bottom of the <ul>

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is my code:

```
var message;
var ul = $('.chat');
var btn = $('#btnEnviar');

btn.click(()=>{
  message = $('#Mensaje').val()
  ul.append('<li>'+message+'</li>');
})
$('#Mensaje').keyup((e)=>{
  (e.which === 13) && ul.append('<li>'+$('#Mensaje').val()+'</li>')
})

rest of the code is here:
[https://codepen.io/willmsha/pen/zyQVPb][1]
```

As you guys can see that I have to scroll down after few times of adding new message to the ul.

 Is there any chance to prevent that except using something like this:

```
window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);
```

So what I wanna do is something like to append the li tag to the bottom of the ul, so I wont have to scroll down when a new mesage is added.

Comment: if you add a dynamic id to each `<li>` you can scrollTo the offset.top of that id.

Comment: `append` already always adds to the bottom. If you want to keep the screen at the bottom, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37300618/215552).

Comment: Please post your code here using a StackOverflow snippet instead of referencing external code sites.

Comment: @HereticMonkey thank you, that was kinda what i was looking for.
connexo actually tried to but failed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the `.scrollIntoView()` method. Add this to your `btn.click` listener:

```
var children = document.getElementsByClassName("chat")[0].childNodes;

children[children.length-1].scrollIntoView();
```

Read more about it here: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_scrollintoview.asp